# How to give one flexdashboard page a different sidebar?

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have an rmarkdown dashboard built with flexdashboard where a global sidebar with many inputs is appropriate for most pages, but there are one or two where a different sidebar is needed. Is there a way to override the global sidebar just for one individual page, or, alternatively, stop the global sidebar from rendering on one specific page?

As an example, the following almost gets me there, but renders the global and local sidebars as overlapping on Page 3, plus adds an odd column of whitespace.

````
---
title: "My Page"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================  

```{r}
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "options", label = "Some Options:", choices = c("One", "Two", "Three"), selected = c("One", "Two", "Three"))
```

Page 1
=====================================  

Column
-------------------------------------

### Some things here. 

Page 2
=====================================  

Column
-------------------------------------

### Some other things here. 
    
Page 3
=====================================     

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "diff_options", label = "Some Different Options:", choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Column
-------------------------------------

### Some very different things here.
````

Looks like this.

[image: Overlapping Sidebars]

I know that I can solve this by just making every page have its own custom sidebar, but there are dozens of them, and that's going to get pretty onerous.

Answer (score 0):

I've used another example in a shinyApp that I recently used.
Bassically, you put the content of the different sidebars in separated conditionalPanels, and you add an id to the tabsetPanel.

In this app, whenever you changed the tab, the selector in the sidebar will change programatically

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabselected==1",
                         selectInput("select_group", label = "Select a Group",
                                     choices = c("Group 1", "Group 2"),
                                     selected = "Group 1")
                       ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabselected==2",
                         selectInput("select_group2", label = "Select a Group",
                                     choices = c("Group 3", "Group 4"),
                                     selected = "Group 3")
                       )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("DataTable", value =1,  DTOutput("my_datatable")),
        tabPanel("Another", value = 2, verbatimTextOutput("text")),
        id="tabselected"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  v <- reactive({
    req(input$select_group)
    if(input$select_group == "Group 1") {
      data <- tibble(`Rows`= paste("Row", 1:4),
                     `Column 1` = rep(0,4))
    } else {
      data <- tibble(`Rows`= paste("Row", 1:5),
                     `Column 1` = rep(0,5))
    }
  })
  
  output$my_datatable <- renderDT({
    req(v())
    DT::datatable(v(), options = list(
      searching = F,
      paging = F,
      ordering = F,
      info = F
      ), editable = TRUE,
      rownames = NULL
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This feels promising but I'm having a hard time getting it to work in the example I provided. Any suggestions? I tried this... `conditionalPanel(condition = "page_no == 'Page 1'", checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "options1", label = "Some Options:", choices = c("One", "Two", "Three"), selected = c("One", "Two", "Three")))` but it's always visible. I guess I don't know how to make the page selection the condition...